# How do I create individual event handlers for buttons added dynamically to a WinForm in Powershell

Tags: powershell, winforms

I am trying to have a dynamically created WinForm where I pass in a dictionary of names (keys) and the url where the image is hosted (values).

The code, loops through the dictionary and adds a button for each 'key' and when the button is pressed, it sets the picturebox to be the image at the url for that button.

There can be a different number of buttons each time (maybe up to 10).

I don't know if my approach (below) is the right one but I get most of what I want. The problem is that the image is only ever 'Mason' no matter which button is pressed.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms


# Define a dictionary of names and image URLs
$image_url_lookup = @{
    'Eric' = 'https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/67/285x190/1758705_1.jpg'
    'Mason' = 'https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/67/285x190/1758732_1.jpg'
    'Other' = 'https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/67/285x190/1758699_1.jpg'
}

# Create a new form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Select Images"
$form.Width = 800
$form.Height = 600
$form.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White

# Create a new table layout panel
$tableLayoutPanel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
$tableLayoutPanel.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill

# Create a new picture box
$pictureBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$pictureBox.Width = $form.Width - 100
$pictureBox.Height = $form.Height - 100
$pictureBox.Left = ($form.Width - $pictureBox.Width) / 2
$pictureBox.Top = ($form.Height - $pictureBox.Height) / 2
$pictureBox.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Transparent
$pictureBox.SizeMode = [System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode]::Zoom

$image_index = 0

foreach ($name in $image_url_lookup.Keys) {
    $image_index++
    $button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button.Name = "Button$image_index"
    $button.Text = $name
    $button.AccessibleName = $image_url_lookup[$name]
    $button.Add_Click({ $pictureBox.ImageLocation = $button.AccessibleName })
    $button.Width = 75
    $button.Height = 23
    
    # Add the button to the table layout panel
    $tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add($button, $i, 0)
}

# Add the picture box to the table layout panel
$tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add($pictureBox, 0, 1)
$tableLayoutPanel.SetColumnSpan($pictureBox, $image_index + 5)

# Add the table layout panel to the form
$form.Controls.Add($tableLayoutPanel)

# Show the form
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$form.Dispose()
```

Comment: Try using the buttons `Tag` property to store the url, not the `Accessiblename`. That is _a label that briefly describes and identifies the object within its container, such as the text in a Button, the name of a MenuItem, or a label displayed next to a TextBox control._. Also, inside the Click eventhandler, I would use `$this` to refer to the button object itself. Like `.. = $this.Tag`

Comment: I do not like TableLayoutPanel and prefer to use a main panel and add an array of child panels.  You want you layout panel to contain 10 cells.  Then to access each picture you need to access each of the 10 cells.  To get each cell use following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getcontrolfromposition?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a [`.GetNewClosure()` call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.getnewclosure?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) in your loop so that each scriptblock *remembers* what `$button.AccessibleName` was while it was assigned, otherwise what happens is that you're always getting the value of the last `$button` created:

```bash
foreach ($name in $image_url_lookup.Keys) {
    $image_index++
    $button = [System.Windows.Forms.Button]@{
        Name           = "Button$image_index"
        Text           = $name
        AccessibleName = $image_url_lookup[$name]
        Width          = 75
        Height         = 23
    }
    $button.Add_Click({ $pictureBox.ImageLocation = $button.AccessibleName }.GetNewClosure())
    $tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add($button, $i, 0)
}
```

A much better approach would be to use the [`$this` automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#this) in your events, that way there is no need for a new closure; this was hinted at by [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) in his comment:

```bash
foreach ($name in $image_url_lookup.Keys) {
    $image_index++
    $button = [System.Windows.Forms.Button]@{
        Name           = "Button$image_index"
        Text           = $name
        AccessibleName = $image_url_lookup[$name]
        Width          = 75
        Height         = 23
    }
    $button.Add_Click({ $pictureBox.ImageLocation = $this.AccessibleName })
    $tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add($button, $i, 0)
}
```

Comment: ".. in **his** comment" please ;)

Comment: @Theo gotcha, you know how things are nowadays, folks get offended sometimes :P

Comment: Yes, I know..  Same thing happening in my country too ;(